# Rails i18n: How to know what is the current language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am aware of how i18n/l10n is usually done in Rails3, and I chose to have a single ERB file that calls `t(...)` for localization. But for a particular part I need something special:

I need to display a string whose **localization is coming from an external database**.

So how can I know the current language, to call the external database with an `en` or `ja` parameter?

Something like $LANG in UNIX. Preferably accessible from view or controller.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
I18n.locale # Get and set the current locale
```

As Oshan Wisumperuma states in the comments, the local is stored in a symbol, like `:en` or `:de` (not a string `'en'` or `'de'`)
in an if statement:

```
if I18n.locale==:en
...
end
```

Comment: for someone who is gonna have next issue. I18n.locale == :en will work but not the I18n.locale == "en"

Comment: This answer helped me out almost a decade later.

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma comment saves my time, thanks